# kibana doesnot shows yellow marked elastic search indexes in discover tab

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am very much new to kibana.
I have loaded mysql table to elastic search using logstash.
and it is listed too in elastic search.
but when i see that index into kibana in Management tab it listed in Yellow color and also it is not listed in Discover tab.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you probably have a single node and your indexes have been created with 1 replica that cannot be assigned to a second node.

Run this command and both indexes will become green again:

```
PUT logstash-*,orderingretailermaster/_settings
{
  "index.number_of_replicas": 0
}
```

Regarding your second question, in order to see them in the Discover tab, you need to go to Management > Index patterns and create an index pattern for both indexes, then you'll see them in the Discover tab.